# How to call casper.start() multiple times

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I would like to call `casper.start()` multiple times in my script.

I have tried:

```
var ids = [1,6,13];

ids.forEach(function(id) {
    casper.start('http://localhost/mypage?id='+id, function() { });
});

casper.then(function() {
....
```

However, only the last id gets executed.

It is possible to call `casper.start()` multiple times?  If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`start()` should only be called once for one `casper` object. You see only one call, because a second call to `start()` resets the internal state. You can use `thenOpen()` to open multiple pages:

```
var ids = [1,6,13];

casper.start();

ids.forEach(function(id) {
    casper.thenOpen('http://localhost/mypage?id='+id, function() {
        this.capture("id.png");
    });
});

casper.run();
```